# TestNG parametrization pass in method

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured, testng-dataprovider

I'm wondering is it possible to put parameters in method when I use testng.xml. I know about put parameteres in test class. I use page object model approach. Here is my code

```
<suite name="dev-parametrization" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Paragraphs-Tests">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.java.tests.ParagraphsApiControllerTests">
        <methods>
          <include name="createParagraph">
            <parameter name="paragraphsURL" value="http://192.168.0.139:8880/paragraphs"/>
          </include>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
```

Below test class

```
public class ParagraphsApiControllerTests {

Paragraphs paragraphs = new Paragraphs();

@Parameters({"paragraphsURL"})
@Test(priority = 1)
public void createParagraph() {
    paragraphs.createParagraph();
}
```

And my method - here I want to use parameter from xml. file. Is it possible? How can I do this?

```
public class Paragraphs {


    String paragraphsURL = "http://192.168.0.139:8880/paragraphs";
    String apiParagraphsURL = "http://192.168.0.139/api/paragraphs";

    public void createParagraph() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = paragraphsURL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the same method name in test class and in `Paragraph` class. I changed the test class method name from `createParagraph` to `testCreateParagraph`.

Testng.xml

```
<suite name="dev-parametrization" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Paragraphs-Tests">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.java.tests.ParagraphsApiControllerTests">
        <methods>
          <include name="testCreateParagraph">
            <parameter name="paragraphsURL" value="http://192.168.0.139:8880/paragraphs"/>
          </include>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
```

Test class

public class ParagraphsApiControllerTests {

```
Paragraphs paragraphs = new Paragraphs();

@Parameters({"paragraphsURL"})
@Test(priority = 1)
public void testCreateParagraph(String paragraphsURL) {
    paragraphs.createParagraph(paragraphsURL);
}
```

Paragraph class

```
public class Paragraphs {

    public void createParagraph(String paragraphsURL) {
        RestAssured.baseURI = paragraphsURL;
    }
}
```

Refer [this tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-parameters/) for more information

Comment: OK I changed this. I added @Optional annotation in test class because I got error earlier public void testCreateParagraph(@Optional String paragraphsURL). Now in createParagraph I added only System.out.println(RestAssured.baseURI=paragraphsURL); and I got null. Test doesn't see value from paragraphsURL parameter in xml file.

Comment: My mistake. Tests must be execute from xml. file. Everything is OK. Thanks for help!

Comment: @goney225 - If you find this answer has solved your problem, please make this the accepted answer.